# Why is animatetoRegion not working when i pass data,

Tags: javascript, react-native

Map failing to animate to region when I try to pass data from API, but works when I hard-code the latitude and longitude. I tried to log the data im trying to pass and i can see it correctly, but just does not animate.

```
const Timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (mapIndex !== index) {
          mapIndex = index;
          const longitude = getListingsApi.state[index].longitude;
          console.log(longitude); //This shows the longtitude correctly.
          _map.current.animateToRegion(
            {
              latitude: getListingsApi.state[index].latitude,
              longitude: getListingsApi.state[index].longitude,
              latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta,
              longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta,
            },
            350
          );
        }
      }, 10);
```

Please what can I do?

Comment: I think your issue here was probably that the api request was a promise and the data happened to be processed async.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good. The only thing that could be wrong is the _map reference. See if you've implemented the reference correctly. I got my animateToRegion working using this answer: [Cannot get ref to MapView - react-native-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047008/cannot-get-ref-to-mapview-react-native-maps)

Answer (score 0):

`const mapRef =useRef()`
do not provide initial params to useRef

```
function animated(){
 if(mapRef.current){
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion(your coordinate)
  }

}
```

````
<MapView ref={mapRef}>
.... any marker
</MapView>```
````